# A tool for automatically testing parameters of methods and throwing ArgumentNullException for .net/VS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, annotations

When I write code I have this strange habit to start my methods with code that just throws exceptions like this

```
public WhateverType MethodName(CrazyObjectType crazyObject, string para2){
    if(crazyObject == null){
        throw new ArgumentNullException("crazyObject");
    }
    if(param2 == null){
        throw new ArgumentNullException("param2");
    }
    if(para2.Lenght > 32){
        throw new ArgumentOutOfBoundsException("para2");
    }

    ...
}
```

Consider some methods have 6 parameters, non of them is allowed to be null and some of them are strings that might not be empty or longer then some value. You can imagine that before I get to actual method logic I write quite some code + my class will be harder to read.

Is there any tool/VS plugin/Resharper plugin/annotation/code snippet for me to not to have to write all this repetitive code ?

Ideal solution would be some declarative annotation something like:

```
[NotNull("crazyObject, param2")] [StringLenght("para2", 0, 32)]
public WhateverType MethodName(CrazyObjectType crazyObject, string para2){
    ...
}
```

- some VS/Resharper plugin that would allow refractoring such parameters so when I rename/refractor some parameter annotation will be synchronized automatically ?

And my ideal image goes even further and I imagine that I can have GUI to automatize process so that I select method click somewhere, check some check boxes for parameters that should not be null and annotation will be generated for me.

Does something like this exist ?

---

*Note: I guess I can always create code snipper that will generate the code but declarative approach and GUI generator would me much better.*

---

**EDIT:** Saying "Consider some methods have 6 parameters" is just an example - I don't think I have many if any such methods. Instead I should have written "consider you have **a lot of** methods that throw some 3-4 `ArgumentException`s".

**EDIT2:** Bad terminology. I realized that what I call "annotation" everywhere in this question and my comments should be probably called "attributes" in .NET if I remember it correctly from my .NET classes.

Comment: You're right that they're called attributes in .NET... but calling them annotations in a "general" way is fine, I think :)

Answer (score 6):

While it's not strictly declarative, I think you should probably look at [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/contracts).

For a bizarre and not-really-recommended way of making null argument testing cheaper, have a look at [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing/). That *only* covers null argument checking though - not other kinds of validity.

By the way, there's nothing strange about the first part of a method just performing argument validation. It's entirely reasonable.

Comment: @Jon Skeet add you btw. - that "strange" was just my best try to avoid same people advising my not to do it, because this or that... I'd expect a lot more tools for this... Including those graphical. For example Eclipse IDE for Java has something like this build in. Is it likely that YOU have missed some solutions to this ?

Comment: @drasto: I don't see why you'd particularly want a *graphical* tool. You're trying to manipulate *text* files, after all. I suspect ReSharper may have some code snippets like this, but it looks like you're after a completely different approach instead of source snippets - and I can't see how the IDE can help you with that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Because if there were annotations for this I think GUI would be the fastest way to do create them. You can have code snippet to create annotation but then you have to write names of parameters... And I like them long. Checking a check box would be faster.

Comment: @drasto: If the annotation were of the form `[NotNull]` before the parameter name, I think I'd rather type that (and use Intellisense after the `[No`, probably) than move my hand away from the keyboard to the mouse, etc.

Comment: @Jon Skeet do you think annotation (or attribute to use correct .NET terminology) can be created easily ? I have never created my own attribute to be honest...

Comment: @drasto: Creating an attribute is easy. Getting it to *do* anything is rather harder... basically you'd need some sort of AOP framework. You could look into PostSharp, which may well support this.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Oh well... No I don't think I'll be happy with post-processing... I wanted native .NET solution :( Maybe I'll just use your "bizarre and not-really-recommended" tool from your blog.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jon on using Code Contracts. Something else you might find interesting is [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I guess I still want annotations with refractoring support.